# VBA color of visible gridlines of tables word

Tags: vba, colors, ms-word

I have more than 500 tables in Word. All of them have horizontal green borders at the top and bottom of the table, and some horizontal lines inside the table. Because of a mistake, some lines inside the same table and between tables have different green colors.

I need to unify the color of visible borders of all tables to the same green (RGB:0,128,0).

I'm very new with VBA. I have been looking at this for weeks without any success.

Here is an example of the tables in my document:
[image: Here is an example of the tables in my document]

Answer (score 0):

this should set the colour of all the borders

it does not change the visibility of any border, or the width, or any other attribute

i tested it on a couple of tables. please test this using a COPY of your document.

```
Sub colorBorders()

    Dim i As Integer

    Dim tabl As Table
    For Each tabl In ActiveDocument.Tables           ' iterate all the tables

        For i = 1 To tabl.Borders.Count              ' iterate all borders for each table
            tabl.Borders(i).Color = RGB(0, 128, 0)
        Next i

    Next tabl
End Sub
```

Comment: Dear jsotola, it works only with the first (top) horizontally border, the others remains the same. I have merged cells at the beggining of the table, maybe the funtion tabl.Borders.Count  is not able to read the number of borders in merged cells?
Thanks for your kind help!